# Separate query compilation from execution in EntityFramework

Tags: performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have a performance problem which narrows down to our app-server. One possible suspect is that in some cases, the time to compile the Linq2Entity query becomes unreasonably long.
We're extending our logging system to include the executed sql.
I plan to use the `.ToString()` method of `IQueriable` to obtain the sql.

1. Will this force EF to compile the query?
2. Will EF use this plan when we enumerate the `IQueriable` and avoid recompiling the query?
3. Is there any downside to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - EF will run your query through the query pipeline (including the provider which generates the actual SQL query),
2. It depends - if you use EF on .NET Framework 4.5 queries are automatically compiled and cached (see [performance considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/hh949853) for more details).
3. Probably not if queries are compiled and cached.